# VeeValidate max_value erroring all the time

Tags: vee-validate

Using a default rule in VeeValidate I am seeing an error anything I type in the input. I have other rules that work fine, I have a regex rule that works fine, but this does not, what am I missing?

I have all the rules on the same validation file so they are being input, and I am getting the error so it must be the implementation of the rule.

The rule is as follows:

```
extend('max_value', {
  ...max_value,
  params: ['length'],
  message: 'Please, only up to {length}'
});
```

However when I have `1` or anything in the field I get an error? I have it set to 20 currently.

Edit: if I delete the `params` and the `message` it works fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [rule documentation](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/rules.html#max-value), you will find that the param is called `max` and not length. If you rename the parameters the implementation still expects `max` prop passed in.